# Debug: How to delete consecutively occurring characters in a string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, duplicates

Below is my code to delete consecutively occurring characters in a string but didn't get the expected outcome...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
           
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args)  {
    
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
            String name= sc.next();
            char[] c = new char[name.length()];
            int j=0;
            boolean check=true;
            //looping through the array to find duplicates 
            for(int i=0;i<name.length()-1;i++){
                if(name.charAt(i)==name.charAt(i+1)){
                     continue;
                }
                else{
                   c[j]=name.charAt(i);
                   j++;
                   check=false;
                }
            }
            //printing the char array
            if(check==true){
                System.out.println(name);
            }else{
                for(int i=0;i<j+1;i++){
                    System.out.print(c[i]);
                }
                System.out.print(name.charAt(name.length()-1));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Outcome :  My code is supposed to delete consecutively occurring characters and print the result for example the if input is `caaaabaaad` the output should be `cabad`

Comment: Please use question body to ask question and brief what problem are you facing ?

Comment: Could you describe problem you are facing with your code? Does it not compile, returns different result than expected (for what input and what is the incorrect result)?

Comment: the problem with my code is it does is not producing results in case of multiple test cases. the code stops after producing output of some test cases.

Comment: Do not provide such information in comments! Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: And hint: use more than one char for your variables. This is not a math formula! Code needs to be read by humans, there is no point in abbreviations like that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this approach:

```
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.next();
        String result = "";

        if (name.length() > 0)
            result += name.charAt(0);
        //looping through the array to find duplicates
        for (int i = 1; i < name.length(); i++){
            if (name.charAt(i) == name.charAt(i - 1)){
                continue;
            } else {
                result+=name.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        //printing the result
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative could be to use java 8 streams.

Steps:

1. Start an `IntStream` from `index = 1` till the end. (Since result value is initially equal to character at index 0)
2. Add character to final result if it doesn't match the last seen character.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            String name = sc.next();
            String result = IntStream.range(1, name.length())
                                    .mapToObj(i -> name.charAt(i) + "")
                                    .reduce(name.charAt(0) + "", (p, s) -> p.lastIndexOf(s) == p.length() - 1 ? p : p + s);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It uses simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a few problems with your code.

Let's label the line numbers as below:

```
01  char[] c = new char[name.length()];
02  int j=0;
03  boolean check=true;
04  //looping through the array to find duplicates 
05  for(int i=0;i<name.length()-1;i++){
06      if(name.charAt(i)==name.charAt(i+1)){
07           continue;
08      }
09      else{
10         c[j]=name.charAt(i);
11         j++;
12         check=false;
13      }
14  }
15  //printing the char array
16  if(check==true){
17      System.out.println(name);
18  }else{
19      for(int i=0;i<j+1;i++){
20          System.out.print(c[i]);
21      }
22      System.out.print(name.charAt(name.length()-1));
23      System.out.println();
24  }
```

The first problem is the combination of lines 1, 19, 20, 21, 22.
I know these lines were put that way because you don't know the length of the reduced string.  So you complicate things with the for loop and then getting the last character from the original string.  However, what if your string ends with 2 of the same characters?

It will print those twice if I'm not mistaken.

The second problem is that you are handling different cases in different blocks.
None of that is needed.

So let's handle all of these issues simultaneously.

```
01  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
02  int lastChar = 65537; // This char will never exist as char is 16 bits in Java.
03  for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
04      char c = name.charAt(i);
05      if (c != lastChar) // perform int comparison so first char will be picked up.
06      {
07          sb.append(c);
08          lastChar = c; // widens c into an int.
09      }
10  }
11  System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

We can simply solve the unknown length issue by using a StringBuilder, ArrayList, etc... The StringBuilder will be the simplest.

We can also use an int, instead of a char to track our last character processed.  We use an int here instead of a char as we need the initial state to be a no-match irrespective of what character is encountered.  Another technique that can be used here is to use Character, but it will be more expensive (heap object) than using int widening on the primitive.

Try it out and let me know if you have difficulty understanding.